# Validators not recognizing values set with patchValue() or setValue()

Tags: typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I have an Angular 8 app that utilizes reactive forms. I have nested formGroups and the validators are working correctly. From another page I pass a state object containing a 'record' used to pre-populate the fields of the form on that page. I am iterating through the form controls and calling setValue() on those controls, this is working as expected. However when submitting that pre-populated form (I use a button not ng-submit) the validators don't see the values set by setValue() and consider the controls invalid.

I have tried all of the `.markAs` methods and `.updateValueAndValidity()`, none of that worked. I've tried them on the individual controls, on their groups, and the form as a whole.

I've removed my `.markAs` and `.updateValueAndValidity()` calls:

```
populateSurvey(record): void {
    for (const i in this.surveyForm.controls) {
      if (record.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // this gets top level formControls
        const control = this.surveyForm.get(i);
        control.setValue(record[i]);
      } else {
        // this gets formGroup.controls of nested formControls
        const fGroup = this.surveyForm.controls[i] as FormGroup;
        const controls = fGroup.controls;
        for (const j in controls) {
          if (record.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
            const control = this.surveyForm.get(i + '.' + j);
            if (record[j] === 1) {
              control.setValue(record[j]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's a truncated version of my form:

```
this.surveyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      eMail: [''],
      org: ['', Validators.required],
      site: ['', Validators.required],
      actId: ['', Validators.required],
      state: ['', Validators.required],
      county: ['', Validators.required],
      beachDescriptors: new FormGroup({
        bdDeep: new FormControl(),
        bdShallow: new FormControl(),
        bdOpen: new FormControl(),
        bdEmbayed: new FormControl(),
        bdFresh: new FormControl(),
        bdMarine: new FormControl(),
        bdPier: new FormControl(),
        bdDrain: new FormControl(),
        bdOther: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.minLength(1))
      }, this.groupValidator()),
        ...
});
```

Expected behavior:
User clicks populate form button on query page, form on survey page gets populated with `record.values` (working).
User submits pre-populatd form and validators validate page including pre-populated fields, (manually input values are working as expected).

Comment: do you have stackblitz for this?

Comment: Stackblitz doesn't work on my work computers due to our security settings, so no.